Обращение к наследуемому элементу в дочернем классе C#
Есть родительский класс Entity, содержащий поля Health и Damage, а также методы GetDamage и Die. Есть дочерний класс Hero, который наследует эти параметры.
Теперь к сути: есть объект который должен при столкновении увеличивать здоровье игрока. Как обратиться к наследуемому полю Health из этого объекта? (В родительском классе поле помечено как public)
Родительский класс:
public class Entity : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public int Health;
    [SerializeField] public int Damage;
    
    public virtual void GetDamage(int Damage)
    {
        Health = Health-Damage;
        Debug.Log($"{gameObject.name}\nЗдоровье: {Health}");
        if (Health < 0)
        {
            Health = 0;
            if (Health < 1)
                Die();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Die()
    {
        
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}

Дочерний класс слишком объемный. Если будут нужны фрагменты кода из него - скину позже.

А что, пробовали и не получилось?

Как обратиться к наследуемому полю Health - также как и к любому другому полю.

Суть проблемы не ясна, Hero должен и так содержать все поля родительского класса, к которым можно обращаться. Заведите метод Heal() который будет лечить игрока. Зачем поле Damage - непонятно.
public class Entity : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int _health; // не видно в наследнике
    [SerializeField] protected int maxHp; // видно в наследнике
    public int Health => _health; // видно везде, но только для чтения

    void Start()
    {
        _health = maxHp;
    }
    
    public virtual void Hit(int damage)
    {
        _health -= damage;
        if (_health <= 0)
        {
            _health = 0;
            Die();
        }
        Debug.Log($"{gameObject.name}\nЗдоровье: {Health}");
    }

    public virtual void Heal(int amount)
    {
        _health += damage;
        if (_health > maxHp)
        {
            _health = maxHp;
        }
        Debug.Log($"{gameObject.name}\nЗдоровье: {Health}");
    }

    public virtual void Die()
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}

И в наследнике
public class Hero: Entity
{
    void Awake()
    {
        maxHp = 1000;
    }

    public override Hit(int damage)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hero: Ай!");
        base.Hit(damage);
    }

    public override Heal(int amount)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hero: Ого!");
        base.Heal(amount);
    }
}

Таким образом вы полностью изолировали логику управления здоровьем в классе Entity.
Ну а при столкновении с аптечкой
[SerializeField] private int hp;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    var entity = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Entity>();
    if (entity != null)
    {
        entity.Heal(hp);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}


Появилась проблема. Все элементы кода, использующие переменную Health, перестали функционировать. Кажется, выражение public int Health => _health; всё сломало. (Поле Health не использует данные из _health, которое берет значение из maxHp.)

@SilentVox что значит перестали функционировать? Подробнее. И как именно использовали.

Перенес функционал, как указано в примерах. Параметр maxHP не влияет на количество (Health) здоровья существа (у меня отдельно прописан дебаг, который срабатывает при смерти и когда я запускаю сцену - существа сразу умирают (значит у них 0 хп), кроме того у меня есть UI отображения здоровья персонажа - он тоже остается на значении 0 после запуска игры).
Переносил системы идентично, только имена полей могут отличаться.

Что интересно - до правок игра полностью работала. Т.е. когда поле Health напрямую работало со значениями - все работает корректно. Когда забирают значение из _health - нет.

@SilentVox я обновлял код, перепроверте, что всё скопировали

@SilentVox если у Hero определён метод Start, не забудьте virtual/override сделать и вызвать base

Нет, метод Start отсутствует. Определены Awake, Update и FixedUpdate

Нашел проблему с персонажем - во время тестов переносил строку public int Health => _health; в метод Awake. Персонаж стал работать (стартует с не 0 хп), но остальные системы (монстры, которые тоже наследуют Entity и скрипт аптечки) - не работают. Монстры исчезают, аптечка не реагирует на столкновение

@SilentVox смотрите у меня в коде, где определяется maxHp и где _health = maxHp. Уберите значения из эдитора, можете maxHp в эдиторе назначить. Если где-то дописывали SerializeField - тоже уберите на том что я показал. Грубо говоря, вы задаете стартовый maxHp, он должен присвоиться в _health. Всё. Вы не можете ничего здесь никуда перенести не сломав. Вы можете только выбрать, каким образом задать maxHp. Но делать это надо либо в редакторе, либо в Awake. Для каждого монстра тоже надо задать maxHp. Тоже либо в Awake, либо в редакторе.

И еще один вопрос на сопутствующую тему: метод Awake выполняется до метода Start, почему перенос сроки с переносом значения не работает в первом случае, но работает во втором?

@SilentVox Строка public int Health => _health; это свойство, вы не можете его никуда перенести не сломав. Это даже синтаксически невозможно, да и смысла никакого не имеет. Health это свойство, можно эту строчку написать по-другому public int Health { get { return _health; } }, это другая запись того же самого. Про свойства, геттеры и сеттеры читали? Свойство используется для инкапсуляции управления здоровья. Чтобы внешний класс не смог здоровье изменить минуя методы Hit и Heal. Это защитит от ошибок при программировании логики.

@SilentVox обратите внимание на => это не = и не опечатка. Если замените, то ничего работать не будет.

Да, я почитал о лямбда-выражениях (правда мало что понял, если честно). У меня именно они в необходимых местах.

@SilentVox ну я тоже не телепат, добавляйте дебаг логов,, смотрите, что куда присваивается, что где получается. Код простой, легко разберётесь.

Я разобрался в процессе, благодарю за помощь
